# Java Runtime.exec() + Minisat

Tags: java, integration, runtime.exec

I programmed an logic gate simulator and netlist parser for `verilog.v` files. 
Now I´d like to do some equivalents checks with a SAT module.

Currently I use `Sat4J` but I´d like to use `minisat2` for the checking. I installed minisat and can run it from console by typing:

```
minisat_static cnf.file
```

My Java Code for starting/exec is, for simple instructions like *ls, ps, less ...* it works perfectly well but if I use `minisat_static <path-to-file>` it doesnt

```
    printLinuxCommand("minisat_static bin/resources/cnf");
}

static void printLinuxCommand(String command) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Linux command: " + command);
    String line;
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(r);
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
    in.close();
}
```

error-msg:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "minisat_static": error=2, Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at circuit.circuit.printLinuxCommand(circuit.java:76)
    at circuit.circuit.main(circuit.java:70)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 5 more
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you try to run the command from the shell and check the output ? Apparently, a file is not found: `cnf.file` ?

Comment: Thats the output for the less cmd (replacing "minisat_static" with "less"): Linux command: less bin/resources/cnf
p cnf 7 25
2 1 0
2 1 0
2 1 0
2 1 0
-2 -1 -1 -1 -1 0
3 2 0
3 1 0
3 1 0
-3 -2 -1 -1 0
4 1 0
4 1 0
4 1 0
4 1 0
-4 -1 -1 -1 -1 0
5 4 0
5 1 0
5 1 0
-5 -4 -1 -1 0
-6 -2 -4 0
-6 2 4 0
6 -2 4 0
6 2 -4 0
-6 7 0
7 0
6 -7 0

Comment: What the `<pre>` means ?

Comment: Im sorry I tried to formate it properly

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the full path to `minisat_static` in your command.

Comment: Ahhhh Im stupid. 
I configured the instruction minisat_static not globally... had a quick fix in bash_profile... wasnt aware of it, Im sorry!
Code works now perfectly